# need help simplifying a program that finds how many times a number appears in an array

Tags: python

i have worked out how to do this using .count(), however i would like to find an alternative way in order to shorten the code.

```
if check[0]==check[1]==check[2]:
  print('jackpot!')
  money = money+100
if check[0]!=check[1]!=check[2]:
  num1 = check.count(1)
  if num1 == 2:
    print('you've won £50')
    money = money+50
  else:
    print('youve lost')
    break
  num2 = check.count(2)
  if num2 == 2:
    print('you've won £50')
    money = money+50
  else:
    print('you've lost')
    break
  num3 = check.count(3)
 if num3 == 2:
    print('you've won £50')
    money = money+50
  else:
    print('you've lost')
    break
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct. Are you sure that this is your code?

Comment: How much shorter than `num1 = check.count(1)` do you hope to get in order to count how many 1's are in `check`?

Comment: This logic seems wrong.  What if the first two are the same but the last is different?  That case falls on the floor.  Also, the check `check[0]!=check[1]!=check[2]` treats the middle one different from the first and last (it will be true if the first and last are the same but the middle one is different).  These seem like bugs.

Comment: You also have apostrophes in apostrophe-delimited strings, which won't work unless you escape them.

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. Please explain, in words, what you are trying to do, and what output you expect. And at least make sure your code compiles before posting it here; as others have mentioned, yours has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have 3 numbers and need to check if there is 2 of the same numbers in the `check[]` list, then either of these will do. First one is using a for loop to iterate the list and uses the `.count()` function. Second one is just using `if elif else` statements, note the nesting. For the first one the list size doesn't matter since it will iterate no matter the size but the second only works for 3 numbers.

```
check = [1, 1, 3, 1 ,5, 6]

for i in check:
    if check.count(i) >= 3:
        print("jackpot!")
        exit()
    elif check.count(i) == 2:
        print("you have won 50")
        exit()
else:
    print("you have lost")
```

or

```
check = [1, 2, 3]

if check[0] == check[1] == check[2]:
    print("jackpot!")
elif check[0] == check[1] or check[1] == check[2] or check[0] == check[2]:
    print("you have won 50")
else:
    print("you have lost")
```